# Bibliography output in RStudio with multiple references

Tags: biblatex, sweave, rstudio

From this link I was able to replicate the references result.

https://texblog.org/2013/08/20/rknitr-automatic-bibliography-generation-with-biblatex-in-rstudio/

How can I add more than one output? And how can I add these references output manually ?

Ive been struggling these last days to find how to do this. But I wasnt able.

Any help?

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@Manual{knitr2013,
    title = {knitr: A general-purpose package for dynamic report
      generation in R},
    author = {Yihui Xie},
    year = {2013},
    note = {R package version 1.4.1},
    url = {http://yihui.name/knitr/},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\section*{Automatic biblatex bibliography generation in RStudio using knitr}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figures/plots-', fig.align='center', fig.show='hold', eval=TRUE, echo=TRUE)
options(replace.assign=TRUE,width=80)
Sys.setenv(TEXINPUTS=getwd(),
           BIBINPUTS=getwd(),
           BSTINPUTS=getwd())
@

<<sample-data-hist-and-box, out.width='0.48\\textwidth'>>=
sampleData <- rnorm(1000, 0,1)
hist(sampleData)
boxplot(sampleData)
@

This document was produced in RStudio using the knitr package \cite{knitr2013} by \url{http://texblog.org}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example in https://texblog.org/2013/08/20/rknitr-automatic-bibliography-generation-with-biblatex-in-rstudio/ uses the `filecontents` environment to produce a `.bib` file and make the example self-contained.

In practice you will usually not have `filecontents` in your document, instead you will have a dedicated file `references.bib` in the same directory as the `.tex` file. That `.bib` file contains all your relevant references.

So your `Rnw` file would look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\bibliography{references}

\begin{document}

\section*{Automatic biblatex bibliography generation in RStudio using knitr}
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
options(replace.assign=TRUE,width=80)
Sys.setenv(TEXINPUTS=getwd(),
           BIBINPUTS=getwd(),
           BSTINPUTS=getwd())
@

<<sample-data-hist-and-box, out.width='0.48\\textwidth'>>=
sampleData <- rnorm(1000, 0,1)
hist(sampleData)
boxplot(sampleData)
@

This document was produced in RStudio using the knitr package \cite{knitr2013} by \url{http://texblog.org}.

See also \cite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and your `references.bib` would look like this

```
@Manual{knitr2013,
  title = {knitr: A general-purpose package for dynamic report
           generation in R},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  year = {2013},
  note = {R package version 1.4.1},
  url = {http://yihui.name/knitr/},
}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
```